# autoSizeColumn() method of XSSFSheet POI doesn't work for Japanese Characters

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I used **Apache POI** for excel file export. But my problem is **autoSizeColumn()** method doesn't work correctly for Japanese character. **It can't show the whole Japanese sentence.** Please anyone help me :-)

Here is my code.

```
public class AutoWidthTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet");
    XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell(1);

    cell.setCellValue("日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語");

    spreadsheet.autoSizeColumn(1,true);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("excelBook.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("excelBook.xlsx written successfully");
}
}
```

The output is :

[image]

Comment: [HorizontalAlignment.FILL](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/HorizontalAlignment.html#FILL) : 2. The column will not be widened to 'best fit' the filled value. Works as designed.

Comment: Apache POI uses local fonts-rendering to decide the width of characters, what do `SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(this, 1, false)` and `SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(workbook)` return for you?

Comment: @AxelRichter ...You're right. I edited the code :-)

Comment: @centic ... I can't understand what did you mean. *SheetUtil.getColumnWidth* return the width in pixels and *SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth* method is used to get character width using the Workbook's default font. But it doesn't solve my Japanese character problem.

Comment: Please add `System.out.println("Width: " + SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(spreadsheet, 1, false) + ", defaultWidth: " + SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(workbook));` to your code, re-run and show us what it prints out, this may allow us to narrow down what the problem is for you.

Comment: Now I calculated the column width manually for Japanese characters and used **sheet.setColumnWidth(columnindex, (calculateContentsLength(content) * 256));**